# Python shebang and newlines

Tags: python, bash, shebang

To make a Python script executable on Linux and bash, one uses the shebang

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

as the first line of the script. If this line happens to end with the Windows-style newline \r\n (carriage return - line feed), instead of the Unix-style newline \n, then bash will not be able to run the script through the Python interpreter.

I am doing cross-platform development in Python. When I work in Windows, the natural newline is \r\n. When I work in Linux, the natural newline is \n. Given that I use Mercurial for version control, what would be the best way to enforce the use of the \n newline in the script file containing the shebang?

Comment: Try adding the shell's comment character to the end of the line.

Comment: can you configure your windows editors to use unix-style line endings?

Comment: I tried #! /usr/bin/env python #, with no luck. I do not want to configure the editor, since I want the working of the shebang to be guaranteed by an automatic process resistant to trivial human error.

Comment: @MarkRansom shebangs are processed by the operating system, not the shell -- this is why scripts (shell and otherwise) can be directly invoked using the `execve()` syscall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The common approach is not to generate the outer wrapper scripts yourself at all, but specify them in your `setup.py` and let them be generated during package installation.

If you do something like the following:

```
setup(
    entry_points = {
        "console_scripts": [
            "script_name": "your.module.name:main",
        ],
    }
)
```

...then, on installation, a wrapper named `script_name` will be generated and installed, and configured appropriately to run on your current platform (shebang line and all). This makes the end-of-line characters in use moot.

Comment: This seems to hit the spot. I need to take care of packaging in any case, so if it can also take care of the shebang, then the problem seems solved.

Comment: @Kaba this solves the problem for Python, but not for other scripts or source files. The SCM method solves it in the general case. So you might also want to set that up, also.

Comment: @Keith This approach also solves problems that the EOL approach doesn't. Have separate `python2.4` and `python2.6` interpreters on your machine? The `setup.py` approach creates the wrapper to use the same one the libraries are installed with, rather than relying on `/usr/bin/env` to just pick the first thing in the path. I agree that there's value to using both, but for the case of Python, relying on EOL conversion alone is an inadequate solution.

Comment: I don't disagree with you. This is the best approach, but only works for Python. But the OP could also benefit from the automated SCM conversion for other reasons.

Comment: An alternative method (not a good one, but one that will work if you are dealing with some upstream code you need to update regularly) would be `cd $(dirname $(which python)); ln -s python python^M` (^M typed as ctrl-v ctrl-m). That makes a filename with a literal carriage return at the end. It is NOT good practice. It is much better to run some tool on the code to convert it. I use `dos2unix` but any number of other tools can work.

Comment: Not speaking to the symlink (and I agree with the assessment that it's not good practice -- can't do that for *every* command, after all), but the other code would be more robustly replaced with `cd "$(dirname "$(command -v python)")"`, such that behavior when directory names contain spaces (or otherwise are values that might be modified by string-splitting and glob expansion) is less surprising.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is common to all scripts that are developed on non-native platforms, not just Python. Most SCM have automatic line ending conversion features. Mercurial can do this, but it's not the default. See the [EOL Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EolExtension).

Comment: The EOL extension seems like a very nice idea. Why is it marked as a feature of last resort?http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FeaturesOfLastResort

Comment: @Kaba I don't know, I was wondering that myself. Subversion also has this feature and it has no such warning. In subversion you can tag each file with attributes, one of which called `svn:eol-style`, which you can set to `native` and it will also do the automatic conversion.  This tag can then be automatically added for certain files.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [EolExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EolExtension) out.

Using [EolExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EolExtension), you can enforce a certain line ending for your repository. Files commited with different line endings get automatically converted.